# Clarification on configuring SDK iOS SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, configuration, ios, mobilepush

1. In regards to configuring the SFMC iOS SDK for use with Mobile Push, how often does the `sfmc_configure()` method need to be called? every launch? (more? less?)

   - Note: I'm using the `MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder` approach rather than a JSON config file.
2. What's going on in the asynchronous portion of the `sfmc_configureWithDictionary:error:completionHandler:` method?

   - I'm configuring with `sfmc_setDelayRegistration(untilContactKeyIsSet: true)` so is there some preliminary contact with sfmc servers or pre-registration being made here?
   - Is there ever a case where the method itself returns `false` but the completion handler succeeds and returns `true`?

**Using: SFMC iOS SDK 6.2.3 -> MobilePush**

Comment: Answer #1 - Yes, sfmc_configure should be called when applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.

Answer #2 - There are both synchronous and asynchronous configure method. We recommend using the synchronous methods. The asynchronous method just let you wait for the configure to complete in your own completion handler if needed. If configure returns false from either the asynchronous or synchronous variants you should stop and examine the error as the SDK will not be initialized if configure returns false and the completion handler will not be called.

Comment: Do NOT make any calls into SDK until the configure method has returned true.